# Filter a pivot table with a dynamic value (>=) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have been working on a problem I have with Excel for a couple of days and cannot find the solution as my VBA skills in Excel are quite low and could not find something similar (or that I could understand) on forums. SO I hope that someone here will be able to help me :D.

How can I automatically apply a filter in a pivot table (via a macro) based on a dynamic value (from a cell, E2, not part of the pivot)?

For instance, if E2 = 3 then I select everything >=3 in the pivot table filter (H1) and refresh it.

So far, I was able to refresh the pivot table and enable multiple selection in the filter using the macro recorder but not the selection of the score according to a dynamic data. See below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Dim Score As String
Score = Range("E2").Value


Range("H1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "Score[All]", xlDataAndLabel _
        , True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Score"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Score")
        .PivotItems(Score).Visible = True

End With
 
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

[image: Excel]